# FME PostGIS reader results in a data set with no geometries

Tags: postgis, geometry, fme-form

Using FME(R) `2023.0.0.1` [build:`23288`] (the same behaviour occurs on `2023.1.1.1` [build:`23636`]) at the time of writing, I'm facing a severe bug(?) with a [PostGIS reader](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME-Form-Documentation/FME-ReadersWriters/postgis/postgis.htm).

Indeed, when connecting to a [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) (14+3.2) database, all my tables and views are correctly read except a few of them, for which no geometry seems to be present when inspecting the results.

But when I load those PostGIS data sets, e.g. using [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) or [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/) 3.34, I can correctly see the geometry field.

FME doesn't reports any type of error so it's really hard for me to understand what's happening and why the geometry is not present in my workspace after the reader has successfully run.

All records are valid `PointZ` geometries. No error is reported by [`ST_IsValid()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html) for example.

How can I find out what's going on under the hood and eventually correct the error if any?

Comment: I think this might be a bug - I would switch on more detailed logging [FME options> translation 'log debug' on] and submit ticket case at https://community.safe.com/s/submit-case